# Excel matching multiple cells for duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to populate a cell where the result is either valid or an error based on the following criteria. I'm not sure if using Match, Lookup formulas will work for this problem.

**Given**

```
       A           B            C
  +-----------+-----------+----------
1 | IntRef    | Value     | Result
2 |-----------|-----------+----------
3 | r01       | Value 123 | Success  (because B4 matches B3)
4 | r01       | Value 123 | Success  (because B3 matches B4)
5 | r02       | Value ABC | Failed   (because B6 differs from B5)
6 | r02       | Value XYZ | Failed   (because B5 differs from B6)
```

**Success Criteria**

> Scan each IntRef (A) column for all duplicate keys. Where they match
>   on a row check the Value column (B). Where all matching cells have
>   **the same** value set their result cell (C) to Success.

**Failed Criteria**

> Scan each IntRef (A) column for all duplicate keys. Where they match
>   on a row check the Value column (B). Where all matching cells have **a
>   different** value set their result cell (C) to Failed.

I am sure there is a formula that can be entered into each cell of column C which will do a lookup for each IntRef  cross referencing the contents of column B where the match occurs. This is going beyond Excel formula knowledge.

Is it possible to create and help formulate the calculation of the success/failed criteria (Column C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to do the trick...

```
{=IF(COUNT(IF($B$3:$B$6=B3,IF($C$3:$C$6=C3,1)))=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$6,B3),"Success","Failed")}
```

Note that that's an array lookup formula (meaning you need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering it).

This formula basically counts the number of times the A and B column values appear together and compares this to the number of times the A column value appears.  If the two counts match, you have success.

Comment: I think your cell references are shifted to the right by one column. If so I get failed in all rows. I should get Success in the first 2. I am not familiar with the array lookup formula. Does this ctrl+Shift+Enter work on Word for Mac? I cannot seem to get it to understand the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2=A$2:A$9,1,0),IF(B2=B$2:B$9,1,0))>1,"Success","Fail")`

Assuming you have your data like this:
[image: sample]

Formula is entered as `Array Formula` in `C2` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then just copy on the remaining cells.
I just added and changed the position of some data for testing.
Hope this works for you. Change the `Range` to suit your data size.